# OpenGL - using two GL programs deforms the positions of vertices

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to use two groups of shaders. ImageShader draws a bigger square, GridShader draws a smaller square. Inside init function I declare the programs (inside new OpenGL::OpenGLShader), after that I insert buffer with position for 
I get the following result:
(the bright square is the ImageShader, declared second)

Render result
[image: Render result]

Here is the code for init() function:

```
gridShader = new OpenGL::OpenGLShader(Common::GetShaderResource(IDR_SHADERS_GRID_SQUARE_VERTEX), Common::GetShaderResource(IDR_SHADERS_GRID_SQUARE_FRAGMENT));
        gridShader->bind();

        //3x positions
        float verticesSquare[6][3] = {
            -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f, 
            0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f, 
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 

        imageShader->unbind();
```

And here are the render functions:

```
void OpenglRenderer::RenderScene() {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        visualize_image();
        visualize_grid();
        renderToImage();
        SwapBuffers(hdc);
    }

void OpenglRenderer::visualize_image()
    {
        imageShader->bind();
        GLint position = glGetAttribLocation(imageShader->shader_id, "position");
        GLint uvPos = glGetAttribLocation(imageShader->shader_id, "uvPos");
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(position);
        glVertexAttribPointer(position, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), 0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(uvPos);
        glVertexAttribPointer(uvPos, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)(2 * sizeof(float)));
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(position);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(uvPos);
        imageShader->unbind();
    }

    void OpenglRenderer::visualize_grid()
    {
        gridShader->bind();
        GLint position = glGetAttribLocation(gridShader->shader_id, "position");
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(position);
        glVertexAttribPointer(position, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), 0);


        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(position);
        gridShader->unbind();
    }
```

Comment: Please state the minimum version of OpenGL you are targetting.

Comment: @keith #version 330

Comment: You are not binding your VAOs when you are rendering (required for the version of OpenGL you are targetting), information on how to properly handle VAOs is poor - most examples on the internet are for older versions of OpenGL. I would do some further research into them until you think you understand them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to draw from two different buffers, you have to make sure that the correct one is bound in the rendering method (or better to say, when setting up the vertex attribute pointer). At the moment, all data is taken from `vboIndexImage` because this is the buffer bound when you call `glVertexAttribPointer`. From your setup code, I guess you shouldn't even setup the vertex attribute pointers in the render methods and only bind the correct VAO instead:

Setup:

```
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vaoIndexImage);
glGenBuffers(1, &vboIndexImage);

glBindVertexArray(vaoIndexImage);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboIndexImage);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(verticesImage), &verticesImage[0][0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

GLint position = glGetAttribLocation(imageShader->shader_id, "position");
GLint uvPos = glGetAttribLocation(imageShader->shader_id, "uvPos");

glEnableVertexAttribArray(position);
glVertexAttribPointer(position, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), 0);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(uvPos);
glVertexAttribPointer(uvPos, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)(2 * sizeof(float)));
```

Rendering:

```
glBindVertexArray(vaoIndexImage);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
```

Similar code should be used for the grid.